# Is it possible to use QTreeView and create a tree without an underlying (allocated) tree structure?

Tags: c++, qt, interface, qt5, qtreeview

I have a tree structure which maps to a QTreeView very well, very similar to how it [works here in this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html); so I have my own `TreeItem` class. All I had to do is map my tree structure to that.

**Here's the problem:** Inside my `TreeItem`, there's a pointer to an interface (to be implemented by the user of my library) that can provide a list of items. So my question: Can I read this interface on the go and create items in my tree *without having `TreeItem` objects created for them?*

So, from that interface, I'd like to have a single fictituous tree node (in the view), which expands to show the elements given in that interface. The text to be displayed can be retrieved from that interface.

**More into the problem**: The reason why I couldn't do this is that in the documentation of [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#details), it says that items are identified uniquely by their parent *object* (but that shouldn't exist, according to my design):

> Model indexes refer to items in models, and contain all the information required to specify their locations in those models. Each index is located in a given row and column, and may have a parent index; use row(), column(), and parent() to obtain this information.

I'm OK with storing the information about the objects in a dynamic way inside the DataModel, but this information should be managed automatically in such a way if something changes in the interface, updating the corresponding tree elements is done on the go without manual memory management.

So do I stand a chance in doing what I'm planning?

PS: I'm ready to have my design called flawed. Please suggest an alternative design if you feel that'd solve the problem.